# yahoo weather in different languages

Tags: api, yahoo

i am trying to get the info from yahoo weather in different languages

http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

but i can only get english results (also just farenheit deegrees, not celsius)
do you know how to configure this web service to get different results? or maybe another multilanguage service?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a multi-language service, however, for displaying Celsius you can add "&u=c" in your URL, for example:
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2442047&u=c